# Map (-1500, 1500) on scale of (0, 100).

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I've a minimum value = -1500 & maximum value 1500.

Now, I've a scale of 0 to 100.

How can I map my min & max value to this scale.

That is, if I select 99 on scale, it should return 99% of the value that lies between (-1500, 1500).

P.S. -As you have guess by now, I'm not good in Maths. So please frame ur answer that I can understand.

Thank You

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of this in two steps:  Step one is to *shrink* your interval down to the right width, and step two is to *shift* your interval over to fit in the right space.

*Shrink*:  The total distance between your maximum value (1500) and minimum value (-1500) is 3000.  You need to fit that into the space between 0 and 100, which is only 1/30 of the total distance you need.  So you need to divide everything by 30.

*Shift*:  After dividing everything by 30, your minimum value is now -50 and your maximum value is now 50.  To get everything to be between 0 and 100, just add 50.

*Summary*:  If $x$ is the value between -1500 and 1500, compute $x/30 + 50$ and it will give you a value between 0 and 100.

To go in the other direction, reverse the steps:  Choose a value between 0 and 100, subtract 50, and multiply the result by 30 to get a value between -1500 and 1500.

Answer (score 2):

For this task, it's often helpful to peform some "normalization". You only have to know how to map an arbitrary interval to the range $[0,1]$, and how to map the range $[0,1]$ to an arbitrary interval.

In order to map a value $a$ from an interval $[min,max]$ to the range $[0,1]$, you can compute

$b = (a-min)/(max-min)$

Now, $b$ will be a value in the range $[0,1]$.

And in order to map a value $b$ from the range $[0,1]$ to an interval $[min,max]$, you can compute

$a = min + b \cdot (max-min)$

---

Given your example: If you want to map the value $99$ from the interval $[0,100]$ to the matching value in the interval $[-1500,1500]$, you can compute the normalized value

$b = (99-0)/(100-0) = 0.99$

and then compute the corresponding value in the target interval:

$a = -1500 + 0.99 \cdot (1500 - (-1500)) = 1470$

Comment: thank you. exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw this in a coordinate system, you are asking for a straight line between the points $(0,-1500)$ and $(100,1500)$. The straight line that intersects these points is:

$$y = 30x - 1500$$

where $x$ is the value on your scale (something between 0 and 100) and the resulting value $y$ is somewhere between -1500 and 1500.